# Is it possible to change the values in a database column to lowercase?

Tags: sql, database

I have an sql database (from an expressionengine install.)

Within the `exp_channel_data` table I have a column `field_id_90` that contains only text values. The problem is all these values are in CAPITALS.

Ideally I would like them lowercase.

Is it possible to run a query or something to change these?

**--UPDATED--**

Thank you for the responses. Just wondering about whether or not its possible to Capitalise the values? Most of the values are single words, but some are "word,word" and some are "word-word"
Is that possible?

Comment: `UPDATE table_name SET field_id_90=LCASE(field_id_90)`? (LCASE can also be known as LOWER in some languges)

Comment: I don't understand your update. What do you want to exactly do when you find "word-word" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
SELECT lower (field_id_90)
FROM exp_channel_data;
```

Comment: Cheers for that! Worked great! :)

Answer (score 1):

`lower()` should work for SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle and PostgreSQL:

```
select  lower(YourColumn)
from    YourTable
```

Comment: You can't use LCASE in `SQL Server`

Comment: @DarrenDavies: You're right.  MySQL supports `lower` as an alias for `lcase` so you can use `lower` there too.

Comment: @DarrenDavies, I don't see sql server mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DanBracuk - it's not.  But that's not the point, `LCASE` is not a function of `SQL Server` which is what Andomar's answer was refering to before the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Use `LCASE()` or `LOWER()`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lcase

Answer (score 1):

Use `LOWER` (SQL Server)

```
SELECT LOWER(Column)
FROM Table
```

Or `LCASE` (MySQL)

```
SELECT LCASE(Column)
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets make my comment an answer:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_id_90=LCASE(field_id_90)
```

LCASE can also be known as LOWER in some languges